# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to Python and OpenCV. But I have managed to write a piece of code which worked fine in the beginning. But now the same code isn't working. The task is, an image has to be captured from the Camera with a droplet and subtracted from the Calibration Image and then the droplet has to be extracted from the image to calculate how many droplets are there and then the corresponding diameters. The code may be a little big and silly because I am new and  wanted to elaborately do all the steps. I am attaching the code and the error below. Please have a look and I hope to find help soon.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import cv2
import scipy

import TIS #For the Camera

from scipy import misc
from scipy import ndimage

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage import measure
from skimage import feature
from skimage import color
from skimage import io


import mahotas as mh

#Droplet Recognition
def DropletRecognition(image_orig,gray_image, line_lowerNozzleEdge):
showImages = 1
image_orig = misc.imread(image_name)
image = image_orig
if showImages == 1:
    print('Measured Image:')
    print(image_orig)
    print('Calibration Image:')
    print(gray_image)
    fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    fig2.suptitle(image_name+'image')
    plt.imshow(image_orig, cmap='gray')
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
cv2.imwrite('/home/Captured_Image.jpg',image_orig) #Saving the Calibration Image
cv2.waitKey(1000)
image_2 = cv2.imread('Captured_Image.jpg')
gray_image_2 = cv2.cvtColor(image_2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Subtracting the Image:
image_subtracted = image-image_calibration
if showImages == 1:
    print('Subtracted Image:')
    print(image_subtracted)
    fig3 = plt.figure(3)
    fig3.suptitle('Subtracted Image')
    plt.imshow(image_subtracted, cmap='gray')
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()

image_subtracted[0:line_lowerNozzleEdge][:] = 0
image_subtracted=image_subtracted[line_lowerNozzleEdge+1:][:]
image_subtracted=image_subtracted.astype('uint32')
image_tmp=image_subtracted
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
image_tmp = ndimage.grey_erosion(image_tmp, size=(6,6))
image_tmp = ndimage.grey_dilation(image_tmp, size=(6,6))
if showImages == 1:
    print('max(image_subtracted) = '+str(np.max(image_subtracted))) 




image_subtracted=image_tmp

thresh_rc = mh.thresholding.rc(image_subtracted) 

thresh_median = np.median(image_subtracted)

thresh=thresh_rc

image_binary = image_subtracted > thresh

image_bin_int=image_binary.astype('uint8')

image_tmp=image_bin_int
im_floodfill = image_tmp.copy()
a, b = image_tmp.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((a+2, b+2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255);
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
im_out = image_tmp | im_floodfill_inv
image_extracted=im_out  
T = mh.thresholding.otsu(image_extracted.astype('uint8'))
labeled,nr_objects = mh.label(image_extracted.astype('uint8') > T)
print('number of detected objects = '+str(nr_objects))
label_array=np.array(labeled).ravel() 
label_array=np.sort(label_array)
pixel_sum=np.zeros(nr_objects+1)
for ii in range(1,nr_objects+1,1):
    n_tmp=np.where(label_array==ii)[0]
    pixel_sum[ii]=len(n_tmp)

ObjectArea=pixel_sum*pixelArea
Radius=np.sqrt(ObjectArea/np.pi)
Diameter=2*Radius
print(' ')
print('object diameters in um ='+str(Diameter/1e-8))
print(' ')
print(' ')
if showImages == 1:
    fig4 = plt.figure(4)
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(labeled, interpolation='none')
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()

return Diameter
return nr_objects

 #Defining the Basic Parameters

#number of calibration images (typ. '1'):
N_EichBilderDuese=1    

#capture calibration image ('1'=yes):
captureCalibrationImage=0

#How many lines used for brightness adaption of measured images, required        for the calibration
#image subtraction:
AusschnittCal_y=230

#Calculate the scale:
rightNozzleEdge=1140
leftNozzleEdge=160
pixelSize=1e-3/(rightNozzleEdge-leftNozzleEdge)
pixelArea=pixelSize**2

#Camera Settings
data = np.loadtxt('KameraEinstellungen.dat',dtype='uint16',skiprows=1)                    
Tis = TIS.TIS(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4])                          


Tis.Create_pipeline() #Creating a pipeline to start the camera
cv2.waitKey(500)

Tis.Start_pipeline()
cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.namedWindow('Window', cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL) 
cv2.waitKey(1000)

#To check if we get an image from the camera or not
counter = 0
error = 0
print ('Press ctrl-c to proceed')
try:
  while ( True and error < 5):
  image = Tis.Get_image()
  if image != None:
  error = 0
  counter = counter + 1
  cv2.imshow('Window', image)
else:
  print ("No image reveived ")
  error = error + 1
 cv2.waitKey(1000) #wait time in ms
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print ('fertig gekuckt')
  print (' ')



#To check for calibration image
if captureCalibrationImage == 1:
  print ('JETZT TROPFENGENERATOR AUSSCHALTEN!')
   raw_input("proced with return")
  print (' ')

counter = 0
while counter != N_EichBilderDuese:
image = Tis.Get_image()
if image != None:
  counter = counter + 1
  error = 0
  tmp='%003.0f' %(counter)
  image_name='Calibration_Image_'+str(tmp)+'.jpg'
  cv2.imwrite(image_name , image)
  cv2.imshow('Window', image)
else:
  print ("No image revived ")
  error = error + 1
 cv2.waitKey(500) #wait time in ms


#Read Calibration Image:
for ii in range(1,N_EichBilderDuese+1,1):
   tmp='%003.0f' %(ii)
  image_name='Calibration_Image_'+str(tmp)+'.jpg'
  image = misc.imread(image_name)
  if ii == 1:
    image_sum=image
  else:
    image_sum=image_sum+image
  print(image_name)

#Process the Calibration Image
image_calibration=image_sum/N_EichBilderDuese
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig1.suptitle('calibration image')
plt.imshow(image_calibration, cmap='gray')
plt.draw()
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
cv2.imwrite('/home/CalibrationImage.jpg',image_calibration) #Saving the Calibration Image
cv2.waitKey(1000) #wait time in ms
image_1 = cv2.imread('CalibrationImage.jpg')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.imwrite('/home/gray_image.jpg',gray_image) #Converting the Calibration Image to Greyscale and storing it

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)      


# Draw Contour
contour_image = cv2.drawContours(thresh,contours,-1,(255,255,255),3)
#Bounding Rectangle to find the lowest nozzle edge
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
contour_image = cv2.rectangle(contour_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
print(x,y,w,h)
line_lowerNozzleEdge = y+h #y coordinate is the top left point, hence adding the height would give the lower edge
print('Lowest Line Edge=', line_lowerNozzleEdge) #Lowest Nozzle Edge
length_lowerNozzleLine = line_lowerNozzleEdge+x
print('Length of the Lower Nozzle Line=', length_lowerNozzleLine)

#CAPTURE DROPLETS
print('Now capture droplets;')
error = 0
print(' ')
print('Press ctrl-c to stop')
print(' ')
try:
  counter = 0
  while ( True and error < 5):
    image = Tis.Get_image()
    if image != None:
      cv2.imshow('Window',image)
      image_name='ActualImage.jpg'
      cv2.imwrite(image_name , image)
      error = 0
      counter = counter + 1
      image=np.squeeze(image)
  Diameter=DropletRecognition(image,gray_image, line_lowerNozzleEdge)
else:
  print ("No image revived ")
  error = error + 1
cv2.waitKey(1000) #wait time in ms

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  cv2.destroyWindow('Window')


Tis.Stop_pipeline()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print ('Program ended')
```

This is the code I have written. Again, the code is very basic. I am also attaching the error that I get.

```
 Press ctrl-c to proceed
Control_Program_Trial1.py:159: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if image != None:
 ^Cfertig gekuckt

Calibration_Image_001.jpg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2437: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
  warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)
(110, 958, 1, 1)
('Lowest Line Edge=', 959)
('Length of the Lower Nozzle Line=', 1069)
Now capture droplets;

Press ctrl-c to stop

Control_Program_Trial1.py:246: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will      result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if image != None:
Measured Image:
[[ 70  63  57 ..., 210 197 203]
 [ 64  69  67 ..., 201 213 207]
 [ 64  65  64 ..., 211 205 218]
 ..., 
 [130 113 100 ..., 255 255 255]
 [120 118 113 ..., 255 255 255]
 [116 125 114 ..., 255 255 255]]
Calibration Image:
[[ 62  56  69 ..., 208 204 207]
 [ 64  71  60 ..., 205 213 210]
 [ 66  70  74 ..., 204 220 208]
 ..., 
 [118 124 120 ..., 255 255 255]
 [123 117 113 ..., 255 255 255]
 [122 120 118 ..., 255 255 255]]
Subtracted Image:
[[  8   7 244 ...,   2 249 252]
 [  0 254   7 ..., 252   0 253]
 [254 251 246 ...,   7 241  10]
 ..., 
 [ 12 245 236 ...,   0   0   0]
 [253   1   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [250   5 252 ...,   0   0   0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Control_Program_Trial1.py", line 253, in <module>
Diameter=DropletRecognition(image,gray_image, line_lowerNozzleEdge)
 File "Control_Program_Trial1.py", line 68, in DropletRecognition
  print('max(image_subtracted) = '+str(np.max(image_subtracted)))   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2268, in amax
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 26, in _amax
return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

Calibration Image
[image: Calibration_Image]
Actual Image
[image: Actual_Image]

Comment: Did you check what the value of `image_subtracted` is right before this exception occurs (line 68)?

Comment: I am unable to obtain the value of image_subtracted right before the exception. I guess it doesn't work right after line 59. After printing and plotting, image subtracted, I actually want to fill out the nozzle region with 0's . Is there any better way to do it

Comment: Please put only the relevant part of the code the next time. Not sure why are you mixing scipy and opencv (look at the reading of the image), also, use saturated function to assure you are within bounds. such as cv2.add or cv2.subtract. The problem is with image substract, try printing it after every operation to see which one is wrong

Comment: @api55 : Thank you and sorry! Since I am new to coding with python. i wasn't aware of which function is available in which library. That's why this confusion. Will have a look. Thanks. And will make sure to put only what is necessary the next time.

Comment: Don't worry and welcome to StackOverflow. BTW I just checked out, and scipy uses PIL images while OpenCV uses numpy arrays... probably they are not compatible at all...  just change the misc.imread function to cv2.imread. BTW you can read the image in greyscale directly with opencv. Also, try going step by step to see where it may fail.

Comment: Are you open to use another code for the same task or want to fix the current code ? Its too long to figure out the issue.

Comment: @I.Newton : open to another code of course. This is just what I could do for the current task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read both the calibration and actual images. I assume both the images are taken without disturbing the imaging setup. If not, you need to do some affine corrections.

Subtract the frames and perform morphological operations to eliminate ambient noise if any. Make sure you compensate every erosion and dilation so that you dont mess with the circle shape much. Find Hough circles in the resulting frame and print out the radius and centre.

[image]

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 


k= np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
img1 = cv2.imread("calib.jpg",0)
img2 = cv2.imread("drop.jpg",0)

diff = cv2.absdiff(img1 ,img2)


d = cv2.erode(diff,k, iterations = 2)
img = cv2.dilate(d,k, iterations = 2)


cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:

    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    print "center : " + str(i[0]) + " "+ str(i[1])
    print "radius : " + str(i[2])



cv2.imwrite("ccc.jpg",cimg)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```